# I want to test the integrity judgment with the Google Play Integrity API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to introduce an integrity check using the Play Integrity API to my Android application.
After implementing it all the way through and testing it from the application that has undergone binary modification referring to the contents [here](https://qiita.com/yukiarrr/items/764adb88f5a485f714d8), the value of `appRecognitionVerdict` in the integrity field of the application in the response is `PLAY_RECOGNIZED`, which means that it is illegal. It didn't seem to be detected.

What kind of cheating actually causes the Play Integrity API to return a value other than `PLAY_RECOGNIZED`?

Comment: I'm also stuck with the same doubt. Has anyone ever tested all verdicts from Play Integrity API?

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#application-integrity-field), it says that there could be other values for this key:

> `appRecognitionVerdict` can have the following values:
>
> `PLAY_RECOGNIZED`
> The app and certificate match the versions distributed by Google Play.
>
> `UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION`
> The certificate or package name does not match Google Play records.
>
> `UNEVALUATED`
> Application integrity was not evaluated. A necessary requirement was missed, such as the device not being trustworthy enough.

I believe the easiest incorrect result to obtain would be `UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION`, for testing it I would try to build a version with an unpublished version code (i.e. greater than any version published on the Play Store) or an invalid package name (but maybe building the app would fail with this option).
In my own tests, simply building an app that is not published on the Play Store (i.e. built locally) is enough to trigger this verdict.

I do not understand exactly what you mean by the binary modification, I mean what changes you made in the binary. The token verification system is probably more sensitive to some binary changes than others.

You could also try to build your app with a different keystore (if you use a keystore that you have listed a SHA in the Firebase settings, it is likely going to be considered as safe/recognized).

Comment: What they are saying by "binary modification" is that they modified the APK that constitutes their android package using tools like Apktool v2.3.4, DnSpy v6.0.3, Il2CppDumper v4.0.0, HxD v.2.2.0.0, etc. (I followed their link and asked chrome to translate to english)

It's not clear to me that Play Integrity API actually hashes the apk nor any part of the installed files, except the certificate. It promises to check for "unmodified binary" but it seems @user54542 has tested it and it does not stop the apk nor the installed application from being modified.